# Find string in file with regex in CMD

Tags: regex, cmd

Hi i have a xml file and need to find a specific string in it.
The string i search for is a value for a xml tag. Then i need to set it to a variable. How do i do it in CMD?

We can assume that file looks something like this

```
<rootElement>
  <childElement.version>1.0.3</childElement.version>
</rootElement>
```

i need to extract "1.0.3" and set it to a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by in CMD ? What is the OS you're using ?

Comment: I mean Windows MS-DOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('find "childElement.version" file.xml') do set "var=%%a"
echo %var%
```

Note: this works with your example, but surely not for every xml file. Batch is not the right tool for xml.